# How to define the friend operator<< for a private class member in a .cpp file, and not in a header?

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading, inner-classes, friend

Compilation of this code fails:

```
class P {
//public:
  class C {
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const C &c);
  };
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const P::C &c) {
  return os;
}
```

error:

```
test.cpp:12:53: error: 'C' is a private member of 'P'
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const P::C &c) {
                                                    ^
test.cpp:6:9: note: implicitly declared private here
  class C {
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Uncommenting `public:` makes this code to compile. And it obviously can be moved to the class itself.

But what is the correct way to define such `operator<<` in a cpp file for a private member class?

Comment: I wonder if `P` has to _also_ friend the function?

Answer (score 5):

To see the private elements of `P` ,  your `operator<<` must be friend of `P`.  So in order to be able to access the definition of class `C`:

```
class P {
  class C {
      ...
  };
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const C &c);
};
```

Then,  your current operator will compile.  But it can only access public members of `C`, since it is a friend of the enclosing `P` but not of the nested `C`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const P::C &c) {
  return os;
}
```

If you also need to access private members of `C` you need to be double friend:

```
class P {
  class C {
    int x;   //private 
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const C &c);  // to access private x
  };
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const C &c); // to access private C
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const P::C &c) {
  os<<c.x; 
  return os;
}
```